# Testing @PreAuthorize annotation with hasAuthority()

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to unit test my apis that have @PreAuthorize annotation. I am getting the cognito groups from the Jwt and using them as authorities. I check the same in the preauthorize annotation in the api methods.
****UPDATE:****
**I get the 404 No mapping Delete profile/VOlUc3F5A_test.txt exists**

Test class:

```
import combackend.StorageController;
import com.backend.config.;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;
import org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Config.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
//@WebMvcTest(StorageController.class)
public class Tests {


    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "admin@domain.com", password = "Password", authorities = "admin")
    public void testDeleteCardProfile() throws Exception {
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .delete("http://localhost:9092/profile/{fileKey}", "VOlUc3F5A_test.txt").with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf())).andReturn();
        Assert.assertEquals(200, result.getResponse().getStatus());
        //  .andExpect(status().isOk());


    }
}
```

Controller method:

```
  @ApiResponses({ @ApiResponse(responseCode = "204", description = "Returns the delete success message"),
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Failed to delete file  : Badrequest"),
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Failed to delete file, NotFound") })

        @RequestMapping(value = "/profile/{fileKey}", consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE, method = { RequestMethod.DELETE })
        @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('admin')")
        public Mono<Boolean> deleteProfile(@AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt jwt, @PathVariable("fileKey") String fileKey) {
                return storageService.removeProfile(fileKey);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message states that `this.mockMvc` is `null`. In the code that you have shared, you are not initializing `this.mockMvc` anywhere.

Perhaps you mean to autowire it

```java
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;
```

Comment: it worked. Thanks. But the test always returns 403 Forbiiden error.

Comment: You may have CSRF protection enabled. Check out [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#test-mockmvc-csrf) section of the documentation.

Comment: yeah, i do. updated the code, request to review. I get the 404 no mapping found error. even though as you can see the controller method has the exact same mapping

Answer (score 0):

The problem with what you are doing is the `mockMvc` isn't configured to work with spring security during tests. Your current solution only deals with `Method Security`[See for clarification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#test-method).

[Setup](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#test-mockmvc) your `mockMvc` correctly and it should work.

```
@Before
    public void setup() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity()) 
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: i changed it. i dont get the mockmvc error but the test always returns 403 Forbiiden error.

Comment: Did you already setup your mockMvc with spring security?

Comment: And also removed autowiring of the mockmvc since you need to build it yourself

Comment: updated the code, request to review. I get the 404 no mapping found error. even though as you can see the controller method has the exact same mapping

Comment: Can you try removing `http://localhost:9092` ?

Comment: You can omit the `http://localhost:9092` entirely